# WPF Xceed Data grid Scroll view

Tags: wpf, xaml, xceed

I have use Xceed data grid with more than 20 columns when i use 20th column and do any action my grid scrollbar start with column no 1 how to avoid such refreshing issue ?

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl AllowDrop="True" AutoCreateColumns="False" ReadOnly="True" Name="xcddgVSMilestones" ItemScrollingBehavior="Immediate"  MouseDoubleClick="xcddgVSMilestones_MouseDoubleClick" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
<xcdg:Column FieldName="Column01" ReadOnly="True" Title="Column 01 ">
<xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext[OriginalDate], StringFormat=\{0: MM/dd/yyyy\}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>.......... up to column20
</xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

This Xaml code was i use

Comment: Add some example code from your application. The error can be anything, we need some code to help you.

Comment: Yeah I added code...